# comparison of Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop with Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop failed

Tags: jekyll, liquid

On Jekyll 3.1.2 (and 3.1.1), In post.html layout, I'm wanting to create a sorted list of posts in a subcategory for it previous/next links. I have it working elsewhere when I know the name of the category, but when deriving the category name I'm having problems appending the post to the array.

Given a group of posts with:

```
categories:
  - topics
  - my-vacation
```

I'm attempting this in the `post.html` layout to create the sorted list:

```
  {% if page.categories.first == 'topics' and page.categories.last != 'topics'
%}{%   assign sorted_list = site.empty_array
%}{%   for topic in site.categories.topics
%}{%     if topic.categories.last == page.categories.last
%}{%       assign sorted_list = sorted_list | push: topic
%}{%     endif
%}{%   endfor
%}{%   assign sorted_list = sorted_list | sort
%}{% endif
%}
```

(`empty_array: []` in config)

But I get this error:

```
Liquid Exception: Liquid error (line 16): comparison of Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop with Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop failed in _layouts/post.html
jekyll 3.1.2 | Error:  Liquid error (line 16): comparison of Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop with Jekyll::Drops::DocumentDrop failed
```

Line 16 is the push to `sorted_list`. If I use `push: 'foo'` or `push: page` I don't get the error, but of course, that's not what I want. When I try to inspect sorted_list, I get an `inspected result must be ASCII` error.

Thanks for any help; I'm at a loss. The first line in the stack trace points to `liquid\strainer.rb` in `invoke` method.

EDIT, more info:

Could it be that its attempting to push the object rather than a reference to it? Or is that expected..

[image: object not reference?]

Comment: I think the error is at `topic.categories.last == page.categories.last` but I cannot reproduce. Did you have a github repository ?

Comment: Thanks, David, let me clean it up and push

Comment: @DavidJacquel Just dawned on me I coulda branched and pushed my broken branch; nevertheless, here's master with the broken portion commented out: https://github.com/arkadianriver/arkadianriver.com/blob/master/_layouts/post.html#L11

Comment: Still not reproducing.

Comment: Thanks.. I ran `jekyll serve --future` on a clone and got the error. I notice, though, that if I remove all but one of the 3006-* posts, the error disappears. Once I add another, the error returns. So, pushing to an empty array is fine. hmm.... Any tips on how I should debug jekyll besides `inspect`? I'm not familiar with ruby unfortunately.. I'm digging through the .rb files now after doing a `jekyll build --future --trace`. I hesitate to report it as an issue if I'm just doing something wrong. :-(

Comment: can you put your local code in a dev branch ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107401/discussion-between-arkadianriver-and-david-jacquel).

Comment: Added date parameter to sort and error disappeared: `assign sorted_list = sorted_list | sort: 'date'`. Posted as [jekyll issue #4727](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4727) for clarification before adding a proper response to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: The error was actually a couple of lines down in the sort. To fix,
add the property you want to sort by to this kind of list:

```
assign sorted_list = sorted_list | sort: 'date'
```

[parkr considered this a bug](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/4727#issuecomment-204120857).
So in Jekyll 3.2, DocumentDrops will sort by date by default.